# Can't get procedural displacement to work at all

Tags: displacement

Trying to follow an Andrew Price tutorial for procedural displacement but when the tutorial goes to procedural displacement I get zero effect, except in surface shadows, when the edges of the object should be displaced, and in the tut look like a sea urchin. Have tried this a few times but can't see where I am going wrong, it seems to be a really simple thing but all the other resources I can find are discussing slightly different procedures. To be clear - I am trying to apply a procedural noise texture (not UV mapped) to a simple object. It doesn't make any difference if I subsurf it or not. He says to change the material option from Bump to Displacement in the material settings but in 2.81 it is default anyway. I want to make a big ocean scene with physically large waves.

I have tried some solutions from the youtube comments such as turning on a bit of subsurf - although that makes no difference and I don't know what it has to do with displacement... Tried turning on experiemental features, double checking I am using cycles... Checked all views, including rendering, this thing is still as smoooth as eggs [image: smooth as eggs]

Comment: It's a [Cycles-only](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/materials/components/displacement.html#displacement-only) feature, only visible in Rendered mode..is that it?

Comment: Yep, definitely cycles.

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6931/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The property you need to change is rather hidden in the UI unfortunately. Blender allows you to change the behavior of Displacement vector inputs per material. So as a result, there is a dropdown box in the **Materials** tab in the **Properties Editor**, under <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Surface</kbd> -> <kbd>Displacement</kbd>:

[image: Displacement Property]

By default that will be set to **Bump Only**. Change it either to **Displacement** - which will displace the geometry - or **Displacement and Bump**, which will first displace the geometry and then apply the same texture as a bump map on top of that. Result looks like this in your file:

[image: Result]

Second, in case you want to go really high with the level of detail, you'll need to enable the **Experiental** feature set to get Adaptive tessellation. Adaptive tessellation (sometimes called Microdisplacement) will give you more geometric details in areas when needed. Here's where to enable it first:

[image: Adaptive]

And here is the checkbox that needs to be enabled in **each SubSurf modifier** where you want adaptive displacement to kick in:

[image: adaptive in modifier]

If you now render, you can see that the detail is a lot smoother, simply because now there are far more triangles in the mesh than before to capture the displacement detail:

[image: result]

Comment: Perfect - thanks!

Comment: Make sure to change the value of the adaptive subdivisionslide from time to time, it sometimes doesn't update like it should @JohnMcCarthy